# Add methods to Selenium Webdriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, selenium-webdriver

Working with Selenium webdriver in ruby, I noticed i can do:

```
driver.find_element(:id => "myID")
```

while this is nice, I would like to be able to do just this:

```
driver.find_element_id("myID")
```

Is it possible somehow to add this method to the WebDriver class?

Comment: Maybe you can open the class like any other class? and add the method? if you can open String, why not WebDriver? class WebDriver def find_element_id(id) ... end end?

Comment: I think it is possible. You need to define your method, inside that method you can call `find_element(:id => "myID")`.. Do you agree with me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`#find_element`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method) is an instance method of the module `Selenium::WebDriver::SearchContext`. So I will open the module `Selenium::WebDriver::SearchContext` and would add the new method as below :

```
module Selenium::WebDriver::SearchContext 
  def find_element_id(id)
    find_element(:id => id)
  end
end
```

Comment: That is interesting. Do I need to know the exact module where find_element is, to create my own custom method?

Comment: @Dbugger yes.. becuase this has been included also `Driver`, `Element` class also.. You need to add the method in the proper location.

Comment: Then how come when I try to extend "module Selenium::WebDriver::Element", I get the message "Element is not a module"?

Comment: @Dbugger see here [SearchContext](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb?spec=svnfd53ae87794d2466b95ee6a4113caedbe0a68695&name=ide-1.0.11&r=2c4c92f464623c1128a3b66d181c6c3ca114cd12) is a module. [Element](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb?name=ide-1.0.11&r=2c4c92f464623c1128a3b66d181c6c3ca114cd12) is a class.